# Как обновить url после переноса сайта, wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Перенёс сайт на другой домен, и некоторые ссылки на изображения остались со старого сайта.
В phpmyadmin делал замену всех ссылок в таблицах wp_posts, wp_options, wp_postmeta.
Ссылки остались в сериализованных данных.
Подскажите, как правильно восстановить эти ссылки?
Эти данные скорее всего были сохранены плагинами в сериализованном виде.
И как лучше сохранять данные при разработке, чтобы не было таких ссылок со старого сайта?

Comment: Лучше хранить связи с id сущностей, а не ссылки. То есть хранить связь не с "ссылка_на_пост" или "ссылка_на_изображение", а связь с "post_id" или "attachment_id". По id поста (вложения и т. д.) вы всегда сможете получить на него актуальную ссылку

Comment: Эта тема уже 50 раз обсуждалась здесь вдоль и поперёк, одно из решений - используйте плагин duplicator он решит все ваши проблемы, если только на сервере не будет ограничений

Comment: [вот решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/Как-правильно-перенести-сайт-на-wordpress/767562#767562)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)